# Ubuntu 20.04 - gui app for easily mount usb drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, automount

I am trying to connect a memory card reader by usb and i am very lazy to do it manually. Considering that this is a quite basic operation, is there a GUI app that I can use to mount the usb drive easily?

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 custom built with i3wm that runs with X. I use the i3wm systemtray only.

I want to find out one **desktop-manager-agnostic** usb mounting utility. Can be cli-only, i don't mind, but a one-liner or something simple enough that doesn't requre me to load my human memory with specific commands.

Comment: You might want to clarify that it's a "memory card reader" - and yes, in both Gnome and and KDE, it shows in the margin on all folder views, and in XFCE in the task bar. Simply plug it in and out while a folder view is visible, if you don't see anything, post a screen shot  with your question as that will answer a lot of questions automatically, such as what GUI and version you're using... I think only guest accounts don't have the necessary privileges...

Comment: @Dagelf ok, updated the question

Comment: Adding to @Dagelf, if you dismount it, you should still see it in a file manager such as Nemo, Nautilus or Dolphin. Just click on the device and it should be mounted again.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy enough to do in a simple script. Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
mntlist=/tmp/mntlist.$$
mounted=/tmp/mounted.$$
mount > $mounted
sudo fdisk -l  |
 grep '^\/dev\/'  |
 sed 's/ [ 0-9.*GMT]* /,/' |
 grep -E -v 'Microsoft reserved|Linux swap' |
 sed  's/,.*//' > $mntlist 

for disk in $(cat  $mntlist) ; do
    if  grep -q  $disk $mounted >/dev/null ; then
        echo $disk is mounted
    else
        echo $disk is NOT YET mounted
        if [ ! -d /mnt/$disk ] ; then
            mkdir  /mnt/$disk
        fi
        sudo mount $disk /mnt/$disk
    fi
done

rm -f $mntlist $mounted
```

and store that in `/usr/local/bin/usbmount` or some easy to remember name.

Note that some will object to the use of `cat` (which is for convenience only here) and the absence of quotes (none of the variable values contain spaces, so not really an issue).